# Problem deciding where to use ceiling colour and wall colour

Tags: painting

We have heating ducts that are covered in drywall making the ceiling lower in 2 parts of the downstairs bedroom. The highest part of the ceiling is 8 ft. Do I paint the underside of the ducts white to match the ceiling or do I totally paint them out in wall colour?Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact situation in house #1 and ended up putting wall paint on both the side and underneath the ducts.

I first put ceiling paint on the underside, but it looked very strange from certain angles -- like lying on the bed -- where you could see all four surfaces in alternating colors.  Then I painted one small section of the duct all ceiling, and another section all wall paint, and decided the wall paint looked better overall.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer will depend on the exact situation, in some situations it will look fine, in others it may look strange as @Niall found.

I have a counter-example where I painted the bottom, and it looks fine. I did have a tough time deciding how to paint the angled bit (which has a duct behind it), but ultimately went with ceiling paint. 
[image]

Comment: This does look a lot better than my setup, I think because your duct is a lot wider than it is high so it feels more like a ceiling.  In my case there was an almost-square cross-section, and the duct ran along the edge of the room.